# Stored Procedure with IsIDenity and cmd.Parameters.Add

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, stored-procedures

I am creating an ASP.NET  Wiki for myself to track the knowlege I gain in C# and other language.

I have created a Stored Procedure to insert a category into a DB, the DB has two fields C_ID(int) and Category(varchar 25). In my ASP page, there is no field for C_ID, it increments automatically by IsIdentiy = true;

When I try to excute it, it fails. What is the best approach to handle this?

Code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.InsertCategory
 @ID int,
 @CATEGORY varchar(25)
 AS

INSERT INTO Wiki
(C_ID, C_Category)
Values  (@ID, @CATEGORY)
    /* SET NOCOUNT ON */
    RETURN
```

Did I miss something to insert from the .aspx page?
            try
            {

```
            //create a command object identifying the Stored Procedure
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertCategory", conn);

            //Set the command type
            cmd.CommandType  = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Category", txtAddCatagory));

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();



        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just omit the `id` from the insert.  If you configured `identity` correctly, the database will take care of increasing the number.  For example:

```
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.InsertCategory(@CATEGORY varchar(25))
AS
INSERT INTO Wiki (C_Category) Values (@CATEGORY)
GO
```

To verify the `identity` is set correctly, if you script the table, the `C_id` column should look like;

```
[C_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
```

Or even better:

```
[C_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
```

Comment: I got that part. Did I miss something to insert in my asp page?

Comment: try
            {
                
                //create a command object identifying the Stored Procedure
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertCategory", conn);

                //Set the command type
                cmd.CommandType  = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Category", txtAddCatagory));

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            }

Comment: @jpavlov: Try to add the parameter with `@`, like `new SqlParameter("@Category"` ?

Answer (score 1):

So you're getting an exception that you cannot insert into an identity column, right? The trick is to not specify the identity column in your insert statement, because it automatically get populated... ;)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.InsertCategory @CATEGORY varchar(25) AS

INSERT INTO Wiki (C_Category) Values (@CATEGORY) /* SET NOCOUNT ON */ RETURN
```